# Unable to format SD-card

Tags: format, raspberry-pi, sd-card, partition

I've got a 16G SD-card.
The SD-card was working great with my Raspberry PI and contained Rasbian OS. However, when I attempted to format the SD-card in order to swap the OS for another one I got stuck. Now I cannot change anything anymore, everything I do either reverts back to the existing state or returns an error code.

fdisk:

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sdb1            8192      122879       57344    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)

/dev/sdb2          122880     7866367     3871744   83  Linux

all attempts to remove, resize or create new partitions result in "succes" (according to Gparted) while the change is reverted back to where I started.

Diskpart in Windows also result in failure.

dd in linux ends in "success" but nothing has changed.

How do I format the SD-card to 16G unallocated (or whatever else there is)?

Comment: maybe stupid but have you checked the [`Lock` trigger](http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTEOZ6Ld5JSy5M0Mh8lyo0jPNY-QPE-kTPRD8zbOrIB4CcAkuiQ) on the sd ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! 
Yes I checked it is unlocked.

Comment: Two and a half years on, Etcher, SD Formatter, macOS, Windows, no matter what I try including deleting files manually one by one they all magically reappear.... I've spent hours on this over the past couple of days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use Window's built-in formatting tool with the default options, and if that doesn't work you could try the SD card association's formatting tool https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar issue

I've got a microsd card that I used for Raspbian. I now want to format the card to FAT32.
I've tried `fdisk` and `mkfs` linux utilities but after I finish the format operation on the card, and I check the card again, it still shows the old format and old partitions.

With `fdisk` - I tried deleting all the partitions and used `w` option to write the result back to the disk.

I've reinserted the card, rebooted the machine after the format option is finished. I also unmounted the card before formatting it.

Not sure what else to do.